# Did i break the promise?

Tags: allah, sunni, forgiveness, jahannam

Salam. I wanted to ask that i promised Allah that i wont watch porn and since then i have not watched it but there was a video where the person wasnt completely naked but there were sexual acts and i watched it so did i break my promise? I promised Allah about porn but in that video , they were covered so is that considered porn? At that time i did not even imagine that this can be considered as porn because they were covered but when i searched on google they said that if there is sexual act in a video , it is porn. So what shall i do did i break my promise ? I did not do it on purpose. I didnt know that it was considered as porn.

Answer (score 0):

**By definition:**

> **"Pornography"** (or "porn") usually refers to representations designed
> to arouse and give sexual pleasure to those who read, see, hear, or
> handle them.

I don’t know if you’re male or female, however, consider the following:

- Was there a specific reason you watched this video?
- What was your intention?
- We’re you aroused upon watching the video?
- Was the video meant to arouse you?

By definition, if there were sexual acts and you did get aroused, **yes, you did watch pornography**.
However, even if you didn’t necessarily masturbate towards the video, you’re still sinful of watching someone of the opposite gender doing something haram.

> “Tell the believing men that they must lower their gazes and guard their private parts; it is more decent for them. Surely Allah is All-Aware of what they do.”
> —Quran 24:30

My best advice would be to repent, show remorse to Allah (swt) over the haram you watched. Even if you didn’t get aroused, but your eyes stared at the opposite gender, you should repent. When Allah sees that you’re remorseful over the sin that you have committed, He will forgive you. Disregard the fact that you made a promise to Allah, He won’t stop forgiving you even if you broke hundreds of promises made to Allah. You’re human! We all sin otherwise we wouldn’t be humans.
Allah knows that you won’t keep a promise refraining from sin, **but** if He sees how you’re trying to put in measures to refrain from committing that sin again, but you still fall here and there, He’ll know you are trying. He won’t hold that grudge towards you over the promise you broke.
**Remorse and regret** are key emotions after sinning that still show you have faith. It shows Allah that you feel horrible over what you have committed rather than being negligent and careless at all.
Don’t let this turn you away from Allah.
Do your best to change your ways to prevent yourself from ever going back to that sin. Find your triggers and learn to tackle them.
And don’t make promises to Allah unless it’s over something you’ll know you’ll be able to keep!

I pray Allah guides us all to be the best versions of ourselves Ameen.

Comment: Oh i mean i said the word porn while promising Him and i had no idea that what i watched was porn. So when i found out that whatever causes sexual excitement is porn , so i decided to not watch such video again but now just please tell me was my promise broken or not. The thing is that i have been into these things from a young age and i want to get rid of them and im trying different ways but everything leads to breaking the promise again. So this time i decided i wont break the promise

Comment: I will try my best not to watch any such thing again but can u tell me was the promise broken or not? Like i didnt know that that was porn. And i also know that we have to pay kaffara so do i have to pay??

Comment: And this is stupid Allah wont believe me if i keep breaking promises. I havent paid kaffara for the promises that i broke in the past because im embarrassed to tell my family and im too young and dont have my own money , i will ask my family to pay kaffara i wont tell them what promises i broke. But can u tell me if this promise is broken or not.

Comment: And another thing u have written "hear" in the beginning . so is hearing something like that , porn too?

Comment: @Sinner Yes he will? Who said He won’t? You’re human. If it really bothers/annoys you so much, quit making promises on things you know you can’t control.

Answer (score 0):

In any promise we make there is the possibility that we cannot hold it. God knows that. Giving a promise before God is the ultimate means to strengthen our will to fulfill it.
It can happen - as in your case - that it happens against our will. It can happen that we have to brake it to avoid greater evil (what is unlikely in your case) or that we fail because our will is not strong enough.

Your intention and circumstances will decide over due repentance.

But even in the last case, the promise doesn't become invalid. So continue keeping your promise as you can.

God is merciful.

Comment: I will try my best not to watch any such thing again but can u tell me was the promise broken or not? Like i didnt know that that was porn. And i also know that we have to pay kaffara so do i have to pay??

Comment: Maybe it's better you do something to repent then all is clear and done. I am not you judge and I don't say you have to.